# Why does Tomcat sometimes return JSP page, sometimes 404 not found?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I just set up Tomcat 7.0.53 to run on my Macbook Air with Mavericks, and yesterday it seemed to run well.

But today, after a reboot, I do the following:

```
cd /usr/local/tomcat/bin
./catalina.sh start
```

and then `http://localhost:8080/foo` will sometimes return the `index.jsp` from `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/foo/index.jsp`, but sometimes a 404 Not Found, when I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>several times on Chrome.

What's more, if I modify `index.jsp`, Tomcat still returns the content of `index.jsp` as of yesterday -- seems like Tomcat may be caching something and despite of that, return 404 sometimes.

The `jsp` file has a line

```
Hey, the server says, it is <%= new java.util.Date() %>
```

and when Chrome can show the content, the time is in fact the current time, and it will be updated correct to the current minute and second.  But sometimes it is 404.  How may this be fixed?

**Update:** yesterday, I did change `conf/server.xml` and made the port 80 and restarted Tomcat using `sudo ./catalina.sh start` because port 80 requires root privileges, and today, I changed it back to port 8080 and started Tomcat as myself... and a minute ago, I started Tomcat as `root` and things seem to work perfectly now.  So is it due to some files being written as `root` and a general user cannot overwrite those files?  How can I make it "back to normal" again so that I can start Tomcat not as root?  (and an O'Reilly book says that I should start Tomcat as `nobody` (for port 8080) or `root` (for port 80 or 8080) -- but I just tried and I cannot even start Tomcat as `nobody` -- it will stop immediately.  So it seemed like if I ever ran Tomcat as `root`, I will need to run it as `root` ever after).

Answer (score 1):

You should not run tomcat as root - rather use portforwarding from 80 to 8080 (see your firewall documentation) or have an Apache (or similar) in front and use mod_jk or a proxy in front of tomcat - Apache knows how to drop the root privileges, and you don't want a public-facing daemon to run as root: Any compromise/security issue would have catastrophic impact immediately.

Once you ran as root, several files - temporary files, logfiles etc. - will belong to root and you'll have to change the ownership back to the user that you're running tomcat as.

On my own servers, I'm typically starting tomcat with a sequence similar to this (nonproduction, testservers):

```
cd /opt/tomcat
chown -R tomcat webapps conf temp logs work
sudo -u tomcat /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

As the startup script is executed as root, it's possible for root to change ownership from whoever the files belonged before - as well as drop its own privileges before starting. The user account that is running tomcat here is literally called `tomcat`.

Some of the directories you don't need under tomcat's ownership - especially in hardened production environments, namely `webapps` and `conf`: You'll need them if you deploy new webapps e.g. through tomcat's manager app. But technically, tomcat doesn't need to write to them, that's why I typically have them only tomcat-owned in nonproduction systems.

Now, is this the reason for the nondeterministic behaviour that you mentioned in the original question? I don't really know - can't explain it. Try changing the ownership back to whatever user you want to run tomcat as (with the above instructions - if necessary prepent them with `sudo` when executing them from the commandline)

Comment: Yes, it does work... basically I am doing on the Mac as, first stopping tomcat, then `cd /usr/local/tomcat` and then `sudo chown -R <my_user_name> *`, and then restart tomcat, and it works nicely again.